# variance vs coefficient of variation

Tags: python, image, numpy, statistics, variance

I need to identify which statistic let me to find on digital image which line   has the highest variation. I am using Variance (square units, calculated as numpy.var(x)) and Coefficient of Variation (unitless, calculated as numpy.sd(x)/numpy.mean(x)), but I got different values, as here:

```py
v1 = line(VAR(x)) 

v2 = line(CV(x))

print(v1,v2)
```

The result:

> (12,17)

Should not both find the same line?
Which one could be better to use in this case?

Comment: You'll likely have more luck on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm confused. Is this a programming question or a statistics question? If it's a programming question, please add a bit of clarity on what the programming quesiton is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Coefficient of variation and variance are not supposed to choose the same array on a random data. Coefficient of variation will be sensitive to  both variance and the scale of your data, whereas variance will be geared towards variation in your data.

Please see the example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(10)
x1= x+10
np.var(x), np.std(x)/np.mean(x)

(2.0571740850649021, -2.2697110381499224)

np.var(x1), np.std(x1)/np.mean(x1)

(2.0571740850649016, 0.1531035017615747)
```

Which one to choose depends on your application, but I'm leaning towards variance in your case.

Comment: @Sergey_Bushmanov I see your point, then, in my case, it seems C.V. could be more useful; because one my interest is about scale, but could you give me more information why the C.V is more sensible to scale? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as my knowledge about images goes, C.V. will not only be affected by variance itself, but also by the fact if this variance happened on white or black pixels (see the example above). As far as I understood your question, you're concerned with variance, not by the fact if this happened on white or black pixels. This is why I suggested use of variance. But in any case the final decision is yours. The primary purpose of my post is to show that Variance and C.V. might produce different results and why.

Comment: @Sergey_Bushmanov thank you, you gave me interesting points to analyze before I choose one of them.

Answer (score 1):

1. Variance defines how much it varies from the mean (No Noise in the data) or Median(Noise in the data).
2. Coefficient of variation defines standarddeviation divided by mean. It always expressed in percentages.